# How to display a calculation result on a New page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just started to learn how to build websites (just as a hobby ) I spent the last few months learning HTML and CSS using books and youtube , also started JavaScript but in my age its very hard to comprehend .

I have a question regarding a simple problem so please do not get annoyed by that , I just couldn't find answers anywhere for now.

I am building a simple units calculator. I decided to use  tags as buttons because that way I was able to design the buttons in the shape I want. There is a text box and a number buttons cluster already attached to the text bar

There is also a units button cluster - basically I want the user to type in (or use the buttons to input the number of units ) then press one of the units buttons (inches , cm etc ).

When a unit button is pressed I want the text box value plus the units name to be displayed in a new page  (input 30 and click on "inches" should open a new window with 30 inches in a

or  elements . I tried to read all the related articles here but i just couldn't understand them. Here is my code - hope you wont make to much fun outa old man :-) thank you ..

```
 <div id="inputbar0>

 <form action="" method="" name="vform">
 <input type ="text" min="-100000" max="1000000"

 placeholder="PEEM it!" value="" id="inputbar1">
 </div>













 <div id="selectionbar">

 <div id="inputdistancem">

  <div id="inputdistance0">
  <li class="num1" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
 class="numbutton1" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num2" name="2" value="2" id="2" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
 class="button2" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num3" name="3" value="3" id="3" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
  class="button3" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num4" name="4" value="4" id="4" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
 class="button4" href=""></a></li>
</div>
<div id="inputdistance1">
  <li class="num5" name="5" value="5" id="5" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
 class="numbutton1" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num6" name="6" value="6" id="6" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
 class="button2" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num7" name="7" value="7" id="7" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
  class="button3" href=""></a></li>
</div>
 <div id="inputdistance2">
  <li class="num8" name="8" value="8" id="8" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
  class="numbutton1" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num9" name="9" value="9" id="9" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
 class="button2" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="num0" name="0" value="0" id="0" onClick=addNumber(this);><a 
   class="button3" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="numdec"    onclick="showme('.')><a class="button4" href=""> 
   </a></li>
   </div>
  <div id="inputdistance3">
  <li class="numce" title="Clear Entry" onclick="reset();" >
   <a class="numbutton1" href=""></a></li>


   <li class="numminus"   onClick="showmem('-')"><a class="button2" 
   href=""></a></li>
   <li class="numdel" title="Backspace"   onclick="del();"><a 
  class="button3" href=""></a></li>
   </div> 


   </div> 
   <br>  
   </form>

  <div id="inputdunits">

  <div id="inputdunits0">
  <li class="MM" alt="MILIMETRE"  title="MILIMETRE (mm)"   ><a    
  href=""></a></li>
   <li class="CM"alt="CENTIMETRE"  title="CENTIMETRE (cm)"><a  href=""> 
  </a></li>
   <li class="KM" alt="KILOMETRE"  title="KILOMETRE (km)"><a  href=""> 
 </a></li>
   <li class="MIM"alt="MICROMETRE"  title="MICROMETRE"><a  href=""></a> 
 </li>
</div>
<div id="inputdunits1">
  <li class="NM"alt="NANOMETRE"  title="NANOMETRE"><a  href=""></a></li>
   <li class="nmile"alt="NOUTICAL MILE"  title="NOUTICAL MILE" ><a  
   href=""></a></li>
    <li class="mile"alt="MILE"  title="MILE" ><a  href=""></a></li>
</div>
 <div id="inputdunits2">
  <li class="inch"alt="INCH"  title="INCH (in)" onclick="test()" ><a  
   href=""></a></li>
   <li class="foot" alt="foot"  title="FOOT (ft)"><a  href=""></a></li>
   <li class="yard" alt="YARD"  title="YARD"><a  href=""></a></li>
   <li class="metere"alt="METERE (M)"  title="METERE (m)" ><a  href=""> 
  </a></li>
  </div>



 </div> 

 </form>
  </div>



  <script > 

 function addNumber(element){
  document.getElementById('inputbar1').value = 
 document.getElementById('inputbar1').value+element.value;
  }
 function del() {
   var inputbar1 = document.getElementById("inputbar1");
  inputbar1.value = inputbar1.value.substr(0, inputbar1.value.length - 
  1);
   }

  function reset(){
   var resetButton = document.getElementById("inputbar1");
  if(resetButton){
    resetButton.value= "";



 }
}
</script>
<script > 


 function showme(element){  document.getElementById('inputbar1').value= 
 document.getElementById('inputbar1').value+element;


 }
 function showmem(element){  
 document.getElementById('inputbar1').value=element + 
document.getElementById('inputbar1').value;}
 </script>
```

I can figure all the JS but I just can't make the thing open in a new page.

Comment: if you want to open a new window of specific size by clicking a button then you could use `javascript` for that sir

Comment: Please fix your html code. As of now, it is malformed (e.g. you have 1 `<form>` but 2 `</form>`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to JavaScript as well, so maybe I'm completely wrong, but I think the best way is to send the data in a get variable in the URL, `example.com?q=7meters` or something. This can be achieved with JavaScript as demonstrated [here](http://burnignorance.com/javascript-performance-tips/how-to-fetch-get-request-data-from-url-on-page-load-using-javascript/) just make sure to escape the data before displaying it on your page. You don't want someone to do an [XSS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack on your website because an old project had some bad JS in it.

I hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: No problem, by the way a more understandable variant of the linked function can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Answer (score 0):

- As @Andreas mentioned remove duplicate end  tag.
- Wrap "li" tag under "ul" tag.
- Assign href value to javascript:void(0); in all anchor    link as it
  prevent from page refreshing.
- Add onclick attr for unit button like this

```html
<a href="#" onclick="test(this)">MM</a>
```

- Add below function in your script :

```js
function test($this) {
  window.location.href = "result.html?value=" + $("#inputbar1").val().trim() + " " + $($this).text();
}
```

Use this [link](http://burnignorance.com/javascript-performance-tips/how-to-fetch-get-request-data-from-url-on-page-load-using-javascript/) to read query string param on new page

Note : Replace "result.html" with your page url.

Note by Joeri: sanitize before displaying on page top prevent [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Exploit_examples)

Comment: Thank you sir for having the time to answer me, i guess it is to complicated for me ... i do not know what "wrap" " "tag." means , i guess i have to do some more serious learning ..

Comment: @VANGOOSE Hope my answer is helpful to you. Tag means Html Element and Wrap means child under the parent. Thanks.